# How Do I Make Enemies In My Game Shoot Missles randomnly?

Tags: random, while-loop, pygame, collision, projectile

So I'm trying to create space Invaders currently and i'm trying to make the aliens shoot at the player randomnly. I've made it so that one projectile or enemy missle is shot at the player, but I can't figure out how I can make this happen from random places where the aliens are located, and how I can make the enemy repeatedly shoot missles,as opposed to just once as it's doing right now. My code that i'm using is down below (variables related to the shooting of the enemy are enemMissleFire and enemymissles)....

```
import pygame
import sys
import time

#initialize pygame
pygame.init()
width = 800
height = 600
# set the size for the surface (screen)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height),pygame.FULLSCREEN)
width = screen.get_width()
height = screen.get_height()
print(width)
print(height)
# set the caption for the screen
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders")




def checkCollision(missles, type, score):
    for missle in missles:
      collision = missle.collidelist((type))
      if collision > -1:
        type.pop(collision) 
        missles.remove(missle)
      missle.move_ip(0,missleSpeed)
      pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, missle,0)

# define colours  you will be using
WHITE = (255,255,255)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
RED = (255,0,0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
YELLOW = (255,255,0)



clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60
s = 25
#load and scale images
smallInvaderImg = pygame.image.load("images/smallinvader.png")
smallInvaderImg = pygame.transform.scale(smallInvaderImg,(s,s))
medInvaderImg = pygame.image.load("images/crabinvader.png")
medInvaderImg = pygame.transform.scale(medInvaderImg, (s,s))
bigInvaderImg = pygame.image.load("images/biginvader.png")
bigInvaderImg = pygame.transform.scale(bigInvaderImg, (s,s))
shipImg = pygame.image.load("images/ship.png")
shipImg = pygame.transform.scale(shipImg, (60,60))

smallInvaders = []
medInvaders = []
bigInvaders = []
enemiesMap = ["sssssssssss",
             "mmmmmmmmmmm",
             "mmmmmmmmmmm",
           "bbbbbbbbbbb"]
invadertype = [smallInvaders,medInvaders,bigInvaders]
dx = 1
dy = 0
x = 240
y = 0
gap = 10
for element in enemiesMap:
  for char in element:
    if char == "s":
      smallInvaders.append(pygame.Rect(x,y,s,s))
    elif char == "m":
      medInvaders.append(pygame.Rect(x,y,s,s))
    elif char == "b":
      bigInvaders.append(pygame.Rect(x,y,s,s))
    x += s + gap 
  y += s + gap  
  x = 240

score = 2


ship = pygame.Rect(width/2,525,60,60)

if ship.right == width:   
  ship.right = width

#missles
maxMissles = 3
missleSpeed = -6
missleWidth = 5
missleHeight = 30
enemmissleWidth = 5
enemmissleHeight = 25
missles = []
missleFired = False
lives = 3

playbutton = pygame.Rect(width/2,height/2,155,90)
playbutton.center = (width/2,height/2)
quitbutton = pygame.Rect(width/2,height/2,155,90)
quitbutton.center = (width/2,height/2+110)
playagn = pygame.Rect(width/2,height/2,155,90)
playagn.center = (width/2,height/2)

playword = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsanms", 35)
title = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsanms", 90)
quitword = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsanms",35)
endscreen = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsanms", 90)
playagaintext = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsanms", 35)

enemMissleFire = False
enemmislist = []
enemymissles = (pygame.Rect(ship.centerx,y,enemmissleWidth,enemmissleHeight))

invaderDirSwapped = False
screenControl = 0

main = True
while main:
  clock.tick(60)
  for event in pygame.event.get():
     if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      main = False


  for element in smallInvaders:
    element.move_ip(dx,dy)
    
  for element in smallInvaders:    
    if element.right >= width or element.left <= 0:
      dx *= -1
      invaderDirSwapped = True
     

  for element in medInvaders:
    element.move_ip(dx,dy)

  if not invaderDirSwapped:  
    for element in medInvaders:
      if element.right >= width or element.left <= 0:
        dx *= -1
        invaderDirSwapped = True
     

  for element in bigInvaders:
    element.move_ip(dx,0)

  if not invaderDirSwapped:  
    for element in bigInvaders:
      if element.right >= width or element.left <=0:
        dx *= -1
        invaderDirSwapped = True
      
  


  key_input = pygame.key.get_pressed()
  if key_input[pygame.K_RIGHT] and ship.right < width:
    ship.move_ip(4,0)
  if key_input[pygame.K_LEFT] and ship.left > 0:
    ship.move_ip(-4,0)
  if key_input[pygame.K_SPACE] and not missleFired:
    missleFired = True
    missles.append(pygame.Rect(ship.centerx,ship.top,missleWidth,missleHeight))
  
  if screenControl == 0:
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    
    texttitle = title.render("SPACE INVADERS", True, WHITE)
    textrect = texttitle.get_rect()
    textrect.center = (width/2, 100)
    screen.blit(texttitle,textrect)

    
    if playbutton.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()) and pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
      screenControl = 1
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,(playbutton), 0)

    if playbutton.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
      pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLUE, (playbutton), 4)

    if quitbutton.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()) and pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
      main = False
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,(quitbutton), 0)

    if quitbutton.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
      pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLUE,quitbutton,4)

    textplay = playword.render("PLAY", True, BLUE)
    textrect2 = textplay.get_rect()
    textrect2.center = (width/2,height/2)
    screen.blit(textplay,textrect2)

    textquit = quitword.render("QUIT",True,BLUE)
    textrect3 = textquit.get_rect()
    textrect3.center = (width/2,height/2+110)
    screen.blit(textquit,textrect3)
  
                           
  if screenControl == 1:
    screen.fill(BLACK)

    if len(missles) > 0:
      if missleFired and missles[-1].bottom < (ship.top - 120) and not key_input[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        missleFired = False
    if len(missles) == 0:
      missleFired = False 
   
    
    if enemMissleFire:
      enemymissles.colliderect(ship)
      enemymissles.move_ip(0,-missleSpeed)
      pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, enemymissles,0)
      
      
    for invader in smallInvaders:
      screen.blit(smallInvaderImg, invader)
    for invader in medInvaders:
      screen.blit(medInvaderImg, invader)
    for invader in bigInvaders:
      screen.blit(bigInvaderImg, invader)
    screen.blit(shipImg,ship)


  
  
  #move and draw missles 

  
  checkCollision(missles,smallInvaders,score)
  checkCollision(missles,medInvaders,score)
  checkCollision(missles,bigInvaders,score)

  if smallInvaders == [] and medInvaders == [] and bigInvaders == []:
    screenControl = 2

  if screenControl == 2:
    screen.fill(BLACK)

    if playagn.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()) and pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
      screenControl = 0
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,(playagn),0)

    if quitbutton.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()) and pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
     main = False
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE, (quitbutton),0)

    if playagn.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
      pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLUE,(playagn), 4)

    if quitbutton.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
      pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLUE,(quitbutton),4)
    
    textend = endscreen.render("YOU WON!", True, WHITE)
    textrect4 = textend.get_rect()
    textrect4.center = (width/2, 150)
    screen.blit(textend,textrect4)

    textplayagn = playagaintext.render("PLAY AGAIN", True, BLUE)
    textrect5 = textplayagn.get_rect()
    textrect5.center = (width/2,height/2)
    screen.blit(textplayagn,textrect5)

    textquit = quitword.render("QUIT",True,BLUE)
    textrect3 = textquit.get_rect()
    textrect3.center = (width/2,height/2+110)
    screen.blit(textquit,textrect3)


  pygame.display.update()
```

Regardless, I can't figure out how I can make it so that projectiles can be shot from random aliens, over the course of the player shooting, and so any help would be appreicated.

Answer (score 1):

### Import Random and Time

this will get the random and time functions built in

```
from random import randint as ran
import time
```

### Get the Number

this will get the time between the previous shot and the next

```
t = ran(Min_Time,Max_Time)
```

### Get The Countdown

this will count a second between numbers

```
time.sleep(1)
t -= 1
print(t)
```

### Shot!

shoot

```
if t == 0:
print('shot!')
```

### FINAL CODE (trumpet fanfare)

```
from random import randint as ran
import time

def randshot(Min_Time,Max_Time):
    t = ran(Min_Time,Max_Time)
    print(t)
    while t:
        time.sleep(1)
        t -= 1
        print(t)
    if t == 0:
        print('shot!')
while True:
    randshot(5,10)
```

Hope this Helped!